# Debian + Grails console: destroys local echo of ssh session after exit

Tags: bash, debian, putty, vagrant

I installed grails on a virtual vagrant box of Debian Squeeze 64.

- the debian box base image is available under http://dominique.broeglin.fr/2011/03/26/squeeze-64-vagrant-base-box.html
- the grails installation used the ubuntu ppa as described on http://www.beeworks.be/blog/post/debian_grails

I connect to the box via Putty. Everything works fine except one really really odd effect:

When I close the grails console with `exit`, the echo of my bash commands is lost. I am still able to execute things, but I do not see what I typed anymore.

The effect can be remedied with Putty's option to force the local echo. But then, each keystroke appears twice until the grails console is closed for the first time.

Any ideas on how to solve that issue? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Try to use the command:

```
stty echo
```

It works well for me.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately

```
stty echo
```

does not help at all. What I have done is blind-type

```
reset
```

in the putty screen which will help temporarily